# links in php functions

Tags: php, image, function, hyperlink

i read and tried all the other threads but i cannot seem to make this work...

i have the following

```
$error_str .= "<tr><th>Warp Links</th><td>";
if($user['location'] > 0 && $user['location'] <= $uv_num_stars) {
    // ensure user is in a system that exists.
    print_link($star['link_1']); 
    print_link($star['link_2']);
    print_link($star['link_3']);
    print_link($star['link_4']);
    print_link($star['link_5']);
    print_link($star['link_6']);
    $error_str .= $auto_str."</td>";
    if(!empty($star['wormhole']))
        $error_str .= "<th>Wormhole</th><td><a href=Navigation.php?toloc=$star[wormhole]>$star[wormhole]</a></td>";`
}
```

and this prints a number link stored in my database, e.g.

```
<1>
```

I need to replace this number with an image. So far i've tried

```
print_link($link['link_1'])<img src='/public/img/mail.png'/>";
```

but i get an unexpected T_STRING

My print_link function is

```
function print_link($link_num)
{
    global $error_str;
    if($link_num) {
        $error_str .= "&lt;<a href=\"Navigation.php?toloc=$link_num\">$link_num</a>&gt; ";
}
```

How can i do this?

Thank you for reading.

This is not a WordPress question.

Comment: I suspect this is really WordPress specific instead of PHP?

Comment: You combine php with html without any <?php tag. The line you've tried so far is a bit confusion and surely not correct.

Comment: not sure what is your boal here, please provide more data on what you are trying to accomplish... and the `T_STRING` error is due to the fact that you can't call a php function and mix it with `HTML` directly - can you please include a biger scope of the code?

Comment: More specifically related to plugin WP-Print.

Comment: Trey you could have provided better description. print_link is not php function. So we can only guess what you need.

Comment: My page is in excess of 1000 lines, im not sure i can fit all that here.

Comment: But you could give us print_link function.

Comment: updated the print_link function.

Comment: If your question is answered please don't edit out the question. Maybe it helps someone else. Please show that you are happy with an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it :)

Comment: im sorry, im editing out the question because this is a bad thread and a dead end .

Comment: @trey: Changing your question to a lot of `iiii`s does not make it better. If you really want to get rid of the question, `flag` it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should start from the basics. Find a programming tutorial, buy a good php book etc. Even if we gave you a working answer you would be stuck with your next problem. You have to put a little effort in learning programming if you want to code PHP.

Some links:

- [How to embed php into HTML (and vice
  versa).](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
- [Control structures of
  PHP.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Comment: vbence, obviously im having problems, thank you for pointing out my inexperience with php, if i knew the answer i wouldnt be on this side of the forum.

Comment: @trey Do not take it personal. Honestly, this is the best help I can give you. This forum is not the right place to expand your knowledge at this point. You should learn the basic priciples of PHP and the control structures of the language. There are good books and sites to start, you simply won't learn it here.

Comment: nothing personal, i apologize if i came out that way, ive spent months on this project im a little frustrated. again im sorry. i know the basics, its just the way the script is compiled.... lets say its not the best to work with.